# Como referenciar a propriedade de objetivo criado com `with TEdit.Create(Self)`?

Tags: delphi, with

Como referenciar a propriedade de um objetivo criado com `with TEdit.Create(Self)`, sendo que o uso desta será utilizada num outro objeto que também está sendo criado como `with TSpeedButton.Create(Self)`?

Segue o código:

```
with TEdit.Create(Self) do
begin
  Name   := 'ed'+IntToStr(i);
  Parent := Self;
  Top    := 0;
  Left   := 0;
  Width  := 50;

  with TSpeedButton.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name   := 'sb'+IntToStr(i);
    Parent := Self;
    Top    := 0;
    //Left := TEdit().Left + TEdit().Width; //Como referenciar o TEdit?
    Width  := 20;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade de utilizar essa cascata?

Comment: Porque você não criar uma variável do tipo TEdit, alimenta ela com o respectivo TEdit que deseja chamar, fica mais fácil. Não é muito aconselhável usar o with, depois fica difícil de analisar o fonte e dar manutenção.

Comment: Na verdade, eu já estava ciente desta forma de referenciar. O modo em cascata é porque estou fazendo tipo um framework. Todos os objetos serão criados em tempo de execução conforme os registros nas tabelas do banco de dados. A dúvida mesmo estava mais voltada ao uso do with em cascata, nesse caso terei mesmo que criar variáveis né.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade de utilizar em cascata a criação do componente,
mas de toda forma você referênciar usando o nome do componente que criou:

```
with TEdit.Create(Self) do
begin
  Name   := 'ed'+IntToStr(i);
  Parent := Self;
  Top    := 0;
  Left   := 0;
  Width  := 50;

  with TSpeedButton.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name   := 'sb'+IntToStr(i);
    Parent := Self;
    Top    := 0;
    Left := TEdit('ed'+IntToStr(i)).Left + TEdit('ed'+IntToStr(i)).Width; 
    Width  := 20;
  end;
end;
```

Eu faria separado, cada um no seu bloco de código:

```
with TEdit.Create(Self) do
begin
  Name   := 'ed'+IntToStr(i);
  Parent := Self;
  Top    := 0;
  Left   := 0;
  Width  := 50;
end;

with TSpeedButton.Create(Self) do
begin
  Name   := 'sb'+IntToStr(i);
  Parent := Self;
  Top    := 0;
  Left := TEdit('ed'+IntToStr(i)).Left + TEdit('ed'+IntToStr(i)).Width; 
  Width  := 20;
end;
```

E o correto ainda seria criar Variáveis para cada componente, dessa forma fica mais organizado e fácil localização dos componentes.

```
var
  vEdtUsuario : TEdit;
  vBtn_Ok     : TSpeedButton;
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu já estava ciente desta forma de referenciar. O modo em cascata é porque estou fazendo tipo um framework. Todos os objetos serão criados em tempo de execução conforme os registros nas tabelas do banco de dados. A dúvida mesmo estava mais voltada ao uso do with em cascata, nesse caso terei mesmo que criar variáveis né.

Comment: Sim, vai incrementando o nome delas com a quantidade de registros que vão sendo retornados pelo Banco.